# How to delete an input field from list of input properly

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to handle a list of input dynamically. However when I put some content inside my inputs and delete one from my list I have a undesired behaviour. The correct item is removed but the item in the last position takes the state of the previous item.

```js
var ListItem = React.createClass({
  
  getInitialState: function() {
   return {
     content: ''
    }
  },
  
  handleChange: function(e) {
   this.setState({
     content: e.target.value
    })
  },
  
  render: function() {
    return <div>
      <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
    </div>
  }
});

var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState : function(){
    return {
      items : []
    }
  },

  deleteElement: function(index, e) {
    this.setState({
     items: this.state.items.filter(function (e, i) {
       return i !== index;
      })
    });
  },

  addElement: function() {   
    this.setState({
     items: this.state.items.concat(<ListItem />)
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    var list = this.state.items.map(function(item, i) {
      return <li key={ i }>
        <p onClick={ this.deleteElement.bind(this, i) }>(-)</p>
        <span>{ item }</span>
      </li>
    }, this);

    return <div>
      <ul>{ list }</ul>
      <p onClick={ this.addElement }>(+)</p>
    </div>
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://facebook.github.io/react/js/jsfiddle-integration-babel.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

I think that the issue could be about my list keys but I do not understand why. How could I remove my list elements without altering any states ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When iterating in render, React reuses component instances (for obvious performance reasons). To discriminate between instances, the prop `key` is used.

In your case when you remove an element, indexes move and therefore you mess with the `key -> instance` association. So list items after the deleted element are not associated with the right instance anymore, that is why some of your list elements seem to have the state of the previous element.

To avoid this problem you should **never use index as key prop**. Use a unique identifier for the data instance instead.

In your case, you could **generate a unique identifier when adding a new element**, and use it as key.

For more information about how lists work in React, read: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html